# Is there a way to drive an object's location by it's position on the Outliner or similar?

Tags: outliner

I've been using Blender for some multi-object 2d scenes with an orthographic camera setup and wondered whether there was a way I could drive an object's Z position based on it's position within the Outliner?

Basically I'm looking to mimic graphical software's (GIMP/Photoshop) layer organisers where the top item on the list is at the top of the render and bottom is at the back.

I'm thinking a driver would work on the Z axis if there's a way to reference the Outliner position but it doesn't look like there is? Would be delighted to be proved wrong.

Thanks for any input.
Matt

Comment: A standard driver (without enabling auto-executing scripts) - probably not. A more advanced driver or just a script that observes outliner and updates positions of objects - sure. The bigger problem is how to stop the Outliner from sorting items automatically or how to recreate an outliner-like control to be used. I see that collections aren't automatically sorted, but still the interface isn't designed to easily rearrange them.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I think this sounds like it might outside my skillset. I'll have to commit some time to it when I can